# How to cast generic parameter to generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, extension-methods

I want to have an extension method to print all contents of IEnumerable< X >

```
public static IEnumerable<T> log_elements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, bool recursive = true)
{
    Form1.log("[");
    foreach (T i in collection)
        if(recursive&&(i.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
            (IEnumerable<>)i.log_elements();//This doesn't work
        else
            Form1.log(i);
    Form1.log("]");
    return collection;
}
```

If it contains IEnumerable< Y >, the method should be called for it too.

I cannot add `log_elements<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>,bool)` because `IEnumerable<T>` matches `T` of original method.

I'm almost sure, that there should be a solution for such simple problem in c#.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you actually need the generic form of `IEnumerable` here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from `IEnumerable<T>` to the non generic `IEnumerable` (which the generic version inherits from anyway).

```
public static IEnumerable<T> log_elements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, bool recursive = true)
{
   logElementsInternal(collection, recursive);
   return collection;
}

private static void logElementsInternal(IEnumerable collection, bool recursive)
{
    Form1.log("[");
    foreach (var i in collection)
        if(recursive && i is IEnumerable)
            logElementsInternal((IEnumerable)i);
        else
            Form1.log(i);
    Form1.log("]");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the function cannot be put inside linq expressions, like `x.Select(...).log_elements().Where(...);` can it?

Comment: No but you can have a generic function that just calls this one. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit note:**
This does not address IEnumerable, but omits the need for reflection.
The primary goal of this code is 'easy' to understand syntax and being as reusable as possible.

If you actually want recursion that the following code should serve your purpose; it is more reusable since it does not rely on variables outside of the method scopes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the top level items including all their recursive descendants.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The generic enumerable type parameter.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The source to traverse.</param>
/// <param name="childPropertyExpression">The recursive property expression.</param>
/// <returns>IEnumerable(<typeparamref name="T"/>)</returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> IncludeDescendants<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>> childPropertyExpression)
{
    // The actual recursion is processed inside the private static method
    // This method is serving the purpose of writing expressions.
    var items = IncludeDescendants(source, childPropertyExpression.Compile());
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> IncludeDescendants<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childPropertyFunc)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        var subSource = childPropertyFunc.Invoke(item);
        if (subSource != null)
        {
            foreach (var subItem in IncludeDescendants(subSource, childPropertyFunc))
            {
                yield return subItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var allChildrenRecursive = MyObject.Children.IncludeDescendants(c => c.Children);
foreach(var child in allChildrenRecursive)
{
    Log(child);
}
```

In this situation every child has a recursive collection of the same type of children.
**Beware of cyclic references, because in that case, this will goes as far as your stack allows. (StackOverflowException).**

Comment: Although useful, this wont automatically recursively iterate items in the collection if type `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Magnus Altough my answer does not answer the question directly; the question had more emphasis on recursion than on reflection. But I will update my answer with a note about that.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need to use reflection to do that.

Comment: @Magnus Sorry, mixed up the question with your answer about IEnumerable ;). I actually meant to shift the OPs 'reflection' approach to a more generic approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = i as IEnumerable<T>;
(IEnumerable<T>) a.log_elements(true);
```

Comment: `i` may be `IEnumerable< T2 >` and casting it to `IEnumerable< T >` will cause exception